# mokutil --import fails on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful, UEFI enabled, goal VirtualBox running

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, uefi

I'm trying to get VirtualBox running on Ubuntu 17.10 Artful with UEFI enabled because I dual boot to Windows 10.

To this end I'm trying to sign my kernel libraries with my own key.

I'm following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/760671/could-not-load-vboxdrv-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-16-04-and-i-want-to-keep-secur) which use `mokutil` but it fails.

Found a couple good [follow up ideas](https://www.queryoverflow.gdn/query/kernel-module-mokutil-failed-to-enroll-new-keys-27_39226185.html) for troubleshooting but they didn't work.

When I run mokutil as `sudo -i` I get the following:

```
root@dt-xubuntu:~/module-signing# mokutil --import MOK.der 
input password: 
input password again: 
Failed to enroll new keys
```

And when I try to set the password for `mokutil` I get:

```
root@dt-xubuntu:~/module-signing# mokutil --password
input password: 
input password again: 
Failed to write MokPW: Invalid argument
```

Even when I add `--root-pw` it fails.

Any ideas on how to get `mokutil` to work or VirtualBox to play nice with UEFI on?

Comment: *(...) or VirtuaBox to play nice with UEFI on?* Simply disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Disabling Secure Boot did the trick.  I can still boot into Windows 10. Thank you @MichaelBay !  (If you post this as an answer I will accept it.)

Comment: You're welcome. Regarding your offer I'd rather not. Reason: A good answer would be something that solved the driver signing problem; disabling secure boot is pretty much common knowledge and there must be hundreds of duplicates here (or very similar situations).